# ion-select does not change text after language changed with ng-translate

Tags: angular, localization, ionic3

I am using ngTranslate for my ionic 3 App. I am using an `ion-select` to change several options of my app (including the language). The problem I have is that the text from my `ion-selects` do not change their text after I choose another language without user interaction (that is, if I click it the options and the main text are showed in the correct language).

I tried to use ngZone in this way without success

```
this.storage.set('userLanguage', lang).then(() => {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            console.log("zone run");
        });
    });
```

Comment: check this one:https://github.com/husainsr/Internationalize-and-Localize-Ionic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, maybe is not the best way to do it but I didn't knew a better way to do it. I have declared a Boolean `showSelects` that I use in an `ngIf` of my selects

```
<ion-select *ngIf="showSelects">
    ...stuff..
</ion-select>
```

Every time the user changes the language I change the variable to `false` and then to `true` again

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue somewhere making the *Option* text do not refresh on the *Select* text.

Anyways, this workaround using `[selectedText]` may help:

```
<ion-label>{{ 'select-2-label' | translate }}</ion-label>
<ion-select interface="popover" [(ngModel)]="select2Value"
            [selectedText]="(select2Value === '') ?
            ('selects-option-txt-all' | translate) : undefined">
    <ion-option value="" >{{ 'selects-option-txt-all' | translate }}</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="text_2">Text 2</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Seems this issue is tracked here https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/8561